# Add log in and sign up links to anywhere in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm developing a website based on the Ultimo template, using a child theme.

Basically, what I want to do is to take the log in and sign up links from top.links and put them somewhere else.

Could anyone please give me advice on how to do it?

If it's through a static block, what code do I have to put in a phtml file?

Thanks.

Edit:

I think this has to be done with mage:helper but I don't know how.

Comment: why don't you go to the template and look at the code it is using to make the login in and signup links ?

Comment: Show some code please?...

Comment: I can't go to the template links.phtml because it doesn't specify each link. It's build up on several XML files from Magento, like Customer.xml, checkout.XML and wishlist.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should be return the links. You can use this in template file.

```
$helper = Mage::helper("customer");
$signupurl = $helper->getRegisterUrl(); // Signup url
$loginurl = $helper->getLoginUrl(); // login url
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it now and let you know.

Comment: @SLaRe If you have doubt let me know